# Mudar a cor de uma imagem no css (jquery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tenho uma imagem na minha página:

```
<img style="border:0;" src="img/corpo_menina.png" alt="" width="320" height="480" usemap="#dtb61iMap" id="dtb61iMap" />
```

Em um momento da minha aplicação, várias mudanças no meu css são feitas para mudar totalmente a cor das coisas, invocando isso com chamadas jquery como segue abaixo:

```
 $("body").css({"background-color" : "black"});
```

Porém, também preciso fazer isso com essa imagem, mas um simples `background-color` não adianta.

Como posso mudar a cor seguindo esse padrão jQuery?

Comment: `CSS` não muda cores de partes especificas de imagem... você poderia adotar mudar a imagem em si. Tendo varias imagens para seus vários esquemas de cores simplesmente mude o `src` da imagem.

Comment: tentei isso também, fiz isso:
`var bordaMenina = document.getElementById("dtb61iMap");
  bordaMenina.src = "img/corpo_meninaY.png"; `
mas não funcionou.

Comment: Vc quer mudar a cor ou o src da imagem?

Comment: É melhor trabalhar alterando o src da imagem mesmo.

Comment: vc quer que a imagem fique monocromática (tipo sempre a mesma imagem só que com cores diferentes) ou quer trocar o arquivo da imagem tipo vermelho.jpg por amarelo.jpg etc.

Answer (score 3):

Uma das técnicas simples que vc pode fazer e colocar a imagem em `preto e branco` e depois colocar uma `película de cor` por cima dela, usando cor rgba, ou Hexadecimal com transparência conforme vc achar melhor. Assim facilita para vc trocar os valores das cores depois com o jQuery ou JS.

Veja um exemplo da mesma imagem em várias cores apenas com CSS. Encapsulei a imagem em uma `div` e coloquei um filtro `grayscale(100%)` depois usando um pseudo elemento `::after` na `div` eu coloquei uma película colorida por cima da imagem e usei um `mix-blend-mode` para fazer uma "mistura" entre a cor e a imagem.

Veja que no exemplo abaixo eu fiz um *blend* com "`scree`" e outro com "`overlay`", vc pode usar qualquer outro blend-mode e ainda ajustar o canal Alpha no cor `rgba` para ter um resultado melhor para cada tipo de imagem.

**OBS:** deixei uns comentários no CSS para te ajudar

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 0;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
div[class] img {
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* filtro que deixa a imagem preto e branco */
}

div[class]::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div.red::after {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); /* .5 é onde vc contra a opacidade da cor rgbA*/
    mix-blend-mode: screen; /* aqui vc pode testar outrs filtros para ver o que da o melhor resultado para sua imagem*/
}
div.blue::after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placecage.com/130/250" alt=""></div>
<div class="peb" ><img src="http://placecage.com/130/250" alt="cor"></div>
<div class="red" ><img src="http://placecage.com/130/250" alt="cor"></div>
<div class="blue"><img src="http://placecage.com/130/250" alt="cor"></div>
```

Documentação sobre os filtros de CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Documentação sobre o Mix-Blend-Mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar a cor da imagem, você pode usar o atributo `filter`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').css('filter', 'brightness(0.3)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/papel-de-parede-autoadesivo-cachoeira-paisagem-natureza-3m-D_NQ_NP_706801-MLB20418926269_092015-F.jpg" />
```

Mais informações sobre o atributo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter